# Compare and map the object using angular 4

Tags: json, angular

I have 2 objects, in this mydata object i have to countrycode to country name.
country name i have to pick it from countries object.

```
countries = [
  {
    "name": "Afghanistan",
    "code": "AF",
    "localizationLang": "en"
  },
  {
    "name": "Albania",
    "code": "AL",
    "localizationLang": "en"
  }
];

mydata = [{
    "orgCode": "ZC27693542",
    "orgName": "B - Sedex Conference Demo Purpose Only",
    "siteCode": null,
    "siteName": null,
    "countryCode": "AF",
    "state": null,
    "product": [],
    "productArea": [],
    "lastDateAudit": null,
    "saqPercentage": 0.0,
    "auditCode": null
},...
];
```

And i want the output object should be

```
[{
    "orgCode": "ZC27693542",
    "orgName": "B - Sedex Conference Demo Purpose Only",
    "siteCode": null,
    "siteName": null,
    "countryCode": "Afghanistan",
    "state": null,
    "product": [],
    "productArea": [],
    "lastDateAudit": null,
    "saqPercentage": 0.0,
    "auditCode": null
},...
]
```

I need to change the country code to country name.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular. It's just basic JS object/array manipulation. Basically you want to merge two arrays. What have you tried so far?

Comment: mydata im getting it though services, there i dont know how to map it

Answer (score 2):

Easy :)

```
mydata.map(x=>{
x.countryCode = countries.find(c=>c.code === x.countryCode).name; 
return x;
})
```

Comment: It worked with a simple assignment `=`? I highly doubt it :)

Comment: Yup. Open console and try it.

Comment: https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/bvXeJZ?editors=0010 - With one `=` it returns always the first country in the list (in this case, Albania), and with `===` it works. Which makes sense.

Comment: Yup, you are right, I copied data from the question where is only 1 country. I just answered it in 30 seconds and forgot about "===" bcs it simply worked :) Anyway that's why you are here

Answer (score 0):

try it

```js
var countries = [{
  "name": "Afghanistan",
  "code": "AF",
  "localizationLang": "en"
}, {
  "name": "Albania",
  "code": "AL",
  "localizationLang": "en"
}];

var mydata = [{
  "orgCode": "ZC27693542",
  "orgName": "B - Sedex Conference Demo Purpose Only",
  "siteCode": null,
  "siteName": null,
  "countryCode": "AF",
  "state": null,
  "product": [],
  "productArea": [],
  "lastDateAudit": null,
  "saqPercentage": 0.0,
  "auditCode": null
}, {
  "orgCode": "ZC27695039",
  "orgName": "Sonata-AB-Member",
  "siteCode": "ZS27695161",
  "siteName": "UEM group",
  "countryCode": "AL",
  "state": null,
  "product": [],
  "productArea": ["50203200", "50201700", "50202300"],
  "lastDateAudit": null,
  "saqPercentage": 13.0,
  "auditCode": null
}];

var newArr = mydata.map(function(value) {
  var country = countries.find(function(countrie) {
    return countrie.code == value.countryCode;
  });

  value.countryCode = country.name;
  return value;
});

console.log(newArr)
```

**demo:**https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QmeEXe

Comment: It works but it's the same answer as @Saso's, just in 5 lines instead of one :) Also, you can make a working snippet directly in your answer (and questions) as I did with your code

Comment: ok  thx  , I am codeing ,Did not notice that someone has responded